# PySide fill empty TableModel

Tags: model-view-controller, pyside, qtableview, tablemodel, qabstractitemmodel

I write a tool with two tableviews side by side. I drag and drop Data between them. Everything works fine, but it doesn't work to get an empty model working. So in the beginning I want to have an empty TableView and add items with drag and drop. That works when at least one object is in, but not with an empty one. with an empty one there isn't even an header.

I think the issue is that the TableView doesn't call the Models headerData when it is empty... but don't know if thats right.
here is my model

It would work if I don't set the empty model, but wait till an item is in the model and set it afterwards. But that's not really nice...

```
class myTableModel(TableModel):
    def __init__(self, headers = [], items = [[]], parent = None):
        super(myTableModel,self).__init__(headers,items,parent)
        self.__items = items
        self.__headers = headers

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.column() == 0:
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled

    def supportedDropActions(self): 
        return QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction    

    def removeRow(self, row, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self.__items.pop(row)
        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True

    def insertRow(self, data,row=0,index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), 0,0)
        self.__items.insert(0, data)
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True        
    def data(self,index,role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()

            if len(self.__items[row])-1 < column:
                return ""
            else:
                return self.__items[row][column]

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            self.__items[row][column] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if len(self.__headers)-1 < section:
                    return ""
                else:
                    #print "%s in section %i" %(self.__headers[section],section)
                    return self.__headers[section]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am probably too late to come up with the answer but the question itself was interesting to me so I dig into it and was able to find a solution.

As it turned out, there are several gotchas to implementing the empty state of the table model in such a way that it still displays the column headers and furthermore allows one to drop stuff on itself.

The first gotcha is that Qt doesn't seem to draw the column headers if `columnCount` method return 0 for the invalid `QModelIndex`. It truly doesn't seem to even bother calling `headerData` method in this case. The solution is to never return 0 from `columnCount` with invalid `QModelIndex` even if the number of rows is actually 0 and our underlying data structure is a 2D array where 0 rows mean 0 columns.

The second gotcha is that you seem to need a custom view subclassing `QTableView` because you need to override `dragEnterEvent` and `dragMoveEvent` to accept drag enters and drag moves **unconditionally**. Otherwise the drop events would have no chance to fire, even if you set the `acceptDrops` property of the view to `True`. The default implementation of `dragEnterEvent` and/or `dragMoveEvent` seems to talk to the view's underlying model and if the model has no rows, the view refuses to accept drops.

The third gotcha is not much kind of a gotcha, it's just that in your model's `dropMimeData` method you need to insert rows if you have none, to make the room for the dropped item.

Here's the full solution for PySide 1.2.1 / Qt 4.8.5 tested with Python 2.7:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, headers = [], items = [[]], parent = None):
        super(TableModel,self).__init__(parent)
        self.__items = items
        self.__headers = headers

        row_counter = 0
        for row_item in self.__items:
            column_counter = 0
            for column_item in row_item:
                idx = self.createIndex(row_counter, column_counter)
                self.setData(idx, column_item, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
                self.dataChanged.emit(idx, idx)
                column_counter += 1
            row_counter += 1        

        num_headers = len(self.__headers)
        for section in range(0, num_headers):
            self.setHeaderData(section, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self.__headers[section])
        self.headerDataChanged.emit(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 0, num_headers)

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self.__items):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        return self.createIndex(row, column, self.__items[row])

    def parent(self, index):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return 

        num_rows = len(self.__items)

        # checking for empty nested columns list within a single "row"
        if num_rows == 1:
            if len(self.__items[0]) == 0:
                return 0

        return num_rows

    def columnCount(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return 0

        # compute the max column count within all rows
        max_column_count = 0
        for row in self.__items:
            column_count = len(row)
            if column_count > max_column_count:
                max_column_count = column_count

        # if there are no real columns, make the column count return the number of headers instead
        if max_column_count < len(self.__headers):
            max_column_count = len(self.__headers)
        return max_column_count

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.column() == 0:
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | \
                   QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | \
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled

    def supportedDropActions(self): 
        return QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction    

    def insertRows(self, row, count, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return False
        if count <= 0:
            return False
        num_columns = self.columnCount(index)
        # inserting 'count' empty rows starting at 'row'
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1)
        for i in range(0, count):
            # inserting as many columns as the table currently has
            self.__items.insert(row + i, ["" for i in range(0, num_columns)])
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

    def removeRows(self, row, count, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return False
        if count <= 0:
            return False
        num_rows = self.rowCount(QtCore.QModelIndex())
        self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1)
        for i in range(count, 0, -1):
            self.__items.pop(row - i + 1)
        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True

    def data(self,index,role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            if row < 0 or row >= len(self.__items):
                return ""
            if column < 0 or column >= len(self.__items[row]):
                return ""
            else:
                return self.__items[row][column]
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid:
            return False
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            if row < 0 or row >= self.rowCount(QtCore.QModelIndex()):
                return False
            if column < 0 or column >= len(self.__items[row]):
                return False
            self.__items[row].pop(column)
            self.__items[row].insert(column, value)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if section < 0 or section >= len(self.__headers):
                    return ""
                else:
                    return self.__headers[section]
        return None

    def mimeTypes(self):
        return ['application/vnd.tableviewdragdrop.list']

    def mimeData(self, indexes):
        mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
        encoded_data = QtCore.QByteArray()
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(encoded_data, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        for index in indexes:
            if index.isValid():
                text = self.data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
                stream << QtCore.QByteArray(text)
        mimedata.setData('application/vnd.tableviewdragdrop.list', encoded_data)
        return mimedata

    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent):
        if action == QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction:
            return True
        if not data.hasFormat('application/vnd.tableviewdragdrop.list'):
            return False
        if column > 0:
            return False

        num_rows = self.rowCount(QtCore.QModelIndex())

        begin_row = 0
        if row != -1:
            begin_row = row
        elif parent.isValid():
            begin_row = parent.row()
        else:
            begin_row = num_rows

        if begin_row == num_rows:
            self.insertRows(begin_row, 1, QtCore.QModelIndex())

        if column < 0:
            if parent.isValid():
                column = parent.column()
            else:
                column = 0

        encoded_data = data.data('application/vnd.tableviewdragdrop.list')
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(encoded_data, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        new_items = []
        rows = 0
        while not stream.atEnd():
            text = QtCore.QByteArray()
            stream >> text
            new_items.append(str(text))
            rows += 1

        for text in new_items:
            idx = self.index(begin_row, column, QtCore.QModelIndex())
            self.setData(idx, text, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            begin_row += 1

        return True

class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.left_model = TableModel(headers=["column0", "column1", "column2"])
        #self.left_model = TableModel(items=[["left0", "left1", "left2"],["left3","left4","left5"]],
        #                             headers=["column0", "column1", "column2"])
        self.right_model = TableModel(items=[['right0', 'right1', 'right2'], ['right3', 'right4', 'right5']],
                                      headers=['column0', 'column1', 'column2'])

        self.left_view = TableView()
        self.left_view.setModel(self.left_model)
        self.left_view.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)

        self.right_view = TableView()
        self.right_view.setModel(self.right_model)
        self.right_view.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)

        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.left_view)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.right_view)

        self.window = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.window.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```